# Creating removeNode() method in python to remove all occurrences of a given key in a linked list

Tags: python, linked-list

I'm currently doing a lab assignment where i need to create a removeNode() method in python to remove all the nodes, in a linked list of [1,3,4, 5, 8,3,5,7,3], containing the value n, which the user will input. The code that I came out with is:

```
    def removeNode(self, key):
       currNode = self.head
       prevNode = None 
       while currNode is not None and currNode == key:
           self.head = currNode.next
           currNode = self.head
       while currNode is not None:
           while currNode is not None and currNode.data != key:
               prevNode = currNode
               currNode = currNode.next
           if currNode == None:
              return self.head
           prevNode.next = currNode.next
           currNode = prevNode.next
myList = LinkedList()
for i in [1,3,4,5,8,3,5,7,3]:
   myList.addNode(i)
choice = int(input(' Please input the value to be remove: '))
myList.removeNode(choice)
myList.printNode()
```

I'm able to remove every integer except for 3 where i always get an attribute error in my 'prevNode.next = currNode.next' line, which is 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'. Why does the attribute error keep being raised and how do I fixed it?

Comment: I guess that’s because 3 is the last node. You should think again about what needs to be done differently if there is no `next` node.

Answer (score 0):

Assume 3 (the last one) is your currNode, what is currNode.Next?

does it pointing anywhere? ... 7-> 3 -> None

Consider changing your "if" statement to stop iterating also when currNode.next is a NoneType

Answer (score 0):

You have lines like this:

```
while currNode is not None and currNode == key:
```

Fix it to

```
while currNode and currNode.data == key:
```

I assume that `.data` field is what you want to compare, not the `currNode == key`, cause `key` is coming as `int`.
This will fix your error.

Also I recommend when you check `if currNode == None:` do just `if not currNode:`. Just makes it more readable.

As for the algorithm, you can do a little simpler version:

```py
def removeNode(self, key):
    currNode = self.head
    while currNode and currNode.data == key:
        currNode = currNode.next
    self.head = currNode
    while currNode and currNode.next:
        if currNode.next.data == key:
            currNode.next = currNode.next.next
        else:
            currNode = currNode.next
```